# Equality of Hecke L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This must be well-known: when are two Hecke L-functions (say with finite
order Grossencharacters) equal ? For instance we have equality of the following
three L-functions for conductor 55 on the corresponding ray class groups:

1) $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-11})$, ideal above 5

2) $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-55})$ trivial ideal.

3) $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$, ideal above 11 and 1 real place.

Thanks!

Comment: Dear Henri, I'm not sure I understand your question completely. Ray class groups correspond to ray class fields, and I'd guess that the L-functions characterize these completely. The Hilbert class field in 2) is $Q(\sqrt{-11},\sqrt{5})$ (if the class number is 2). The ray class field modulo $5$ of the first field is $Q(\sqrt{-11},\zeta_5)$ - are you talking about the quadratic character with conductor 5 then? In case 3) you only get the field from 2) if you look at the quadratic character modulo 11 and both places at infinity. Could you make the question more precise?

Comment: Since the class number in 2) is 4, the Hilbert class field is larger, but the fields still don't match. My guess is that the characters are quadratic, and that there should be 2 real places in 3).

Comment: Indeed, the characters are all quadratic, I maintain 1 real place in 3), and the common L-function is $\sum_n a(n)/n^s$ with $a(n)=[1,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,0,...]$

Comment: I'm still confused. Could it be that these L-functions are products of L-functions for conjugate characters of order 4? The L-functions for quadratic characters seem to give something different. If my guess is correct I think I know what's going on, but I'll need a day or two to go through the details.

Comment: In this special case everything happens in the Hilbert class field of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-55})$ which is a $D_4$ degree 8 Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$, and you can identify the above L-functions with a suitable Artin L function. I was asking something more general, but this is a partial answer.

Comment: Is the answer "when the associated Galois representations are isomorphic" or does this somehow not encapsulate every case you're interested in?